# Makefile assign command output to variable

Tags: makefile

I have a script that compresses my css files and outputs the filename of the output file.
I'm trying to build a makefile to automatize the process:

```
all:
    @echo "Compiling CSS"
    CSS_OUTPUT=$(shell php minify_css.php )
    echo $(CSS_OUTPUT)
```

I'm trying to store the output filename in CSS_OUTPUT variable, but I'm doing something wrong, as this whole makefile just prints:

```
$ make
abcdefg.css
Compiling CSS
CSS_OUTPUT=
echo
```

So output is not assigned to `CSS_OUTPUT`. Also, why is php output printed before the `@echo "Compiling CSS"`?

I've tried with this:

```
all:
    @echo "Compiling CSS"
    CSS_OUTPUT=$(shell echo php minify_css.php )
    echo $(CSS_OUTPUT)
```

But it only gets worse:

```
$ make
Compiling CSS
CSS_OUTPUT=php minify_css.php
./minify_css.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
./minify_css.php: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `dirname'
./minify_css.php: line 3: `require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'maintenance.php' );'
make: *** [css] Error 2
```

**Edit**
Following the answer provided in comments, which suggests using eval:

```
@echo "Compiling CSS"
$(eval CSS_OUTPUT:=$(shell php minify_css.php))
echo ${CSS_OUTPUT}
```

Outputs:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Comment: I've read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019989/how-to-assign-the-output-of-a-command-to-a-makefile-variable

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373081/assign-a-makefile-variable-value-to-a-bash-command-result

Comment: None of them answers my problem...

Comment: How about [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909188/define-make-variable-at-rule-execution-time)?

Comment: Using the eval throws me this: make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Comment: Why do you want to store the output of php in a variable? Do you want to use it for something else? If not, you can just leave out `CSS_OUTPUT` and the `$(shell ...)` function, and just run the php command as part of the recipe, since the result gets echoed anyway.

Comment: Yes, I want to use its output for something else obviously...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make works in two phases. First, it reads in the makefile, evaluates variables and builds a dependency graph. Make functions also get evaluated during this phase. In the second phase it executes the necessary recipes to update the main target. This means the `$(shell ...)` function call gets expanded during the first phase, before any recipe is run. The output of the command is substituted for the shell function call, but I suspect the output of the php command doesn't go to STDOUT, so instead of ending up with `CSS_OUTPUT=abcdefg.css` (which would be what you want), `abcdefg.css` is echoed to the screen and the result of the shell function is empty.

Next the recipe is executed, but when this is done, each line is run in a separate shell instance, so the commands on different lines in a recipe have no access to shell variables set on another line (which would be useless in this case anyway, because of the previous issue). One way to counter this is to glue the lines together by ending them with a semicolon and a backslash. Now they get executed as one line in a single shell instance.

Another problem is that in the last line of the recipe, you don't refer to a shell variable (which is what CSS_OUTPUT is), but to a makefile variable that has never been set.

Is there any reason why you don't just do it this way:

```
all:
    @echo "Compiling CSS"
    php minify_css.php
```

Comment: The reason I need its output is I want to act on the file it generates (move, remove, copy, etc...), but I simplified the makefile to expose my problem. I will try to modify the php script to output to STDOUT (I'm using echo`s).

Comment: Is there no way to know the filename in advance? Is it automatically generated? I'm starting to wonder if `make` is really the best tool for this; it's hard to tell from this simplified makefile, but perhaps a good script is easier.

Comment: the filename is automatically generated, and somewhat random

Answer (score 4):

### Problem & Solution

I've run into the same issue myself.  I've found a way to work around it, but it's definitely less than ideal.

As described, the issue comes down to when the `$(shell)` command is executed.  It's executed when the makefile variables are evaluated, which is before any of the targets have been resolved or processed.  To work around this, you can break the `$(shell)` command out to occur in a separate invocation of the makefile.  To get tricky, I just created a "hidden" target for all my post-file-creation work within the same file, and made a recursive make call to my same makefile.  The result looks something like this:

```
override MY_MAKEFILE:=$(MAKEFILE_LIST)
override MY_MAKE_INVOCATION_CMD_LINE:=$(MAKE) -C $(CURDIR) $(if $(MY_MAKEFILE),-f $(MY_MAKEFILE),) --no-print-directory

all: minify_css.php
    @echo "Compiling CSS"
    @$(MY_MAKE_INVOCATION_CMD_LINE) all_hid

minify_css.php:
    <create the minify_css.php file here>    

all_hid:
    @$(MY_MAKE_INVOCATION_CMD_LINE) print_css_hid CSS_OUTPUT=$(shell php minify_css.php )

print_css_hid :
    echo $(CSS_OUTPUT)
```

### Explanation

#### The override commands

The first line of this handles forcibly setting a variable that cannot be overridden from the command-line to collect the name of the makefile.  The first line MUST be called as the absolute first line in your makefile since including other makefiles can change this and it doesn't work from within included makefiles.  Of note is the fact that this will be empty if you didn't specify a makefile on the command-line, which should mean it can be called the same way when invoked from within the makefile.

The second line just constructs the call to the makefile by setting some default options like changing to the current directory the makefile command-line was originally invoked from and only including the specification of the makefile to use if it was included in the original call.

Note that these first two lines are currently implemented in my build system so they do in fact work for multiple nested recursive calls to the same makefile.

#### Recursive Call

Following these two lines are the important ones that answer your original query.  To demonstrate file creation as opposed to just using a shell command's return, I pretended your file also needs to create the `minify_css.php` file.  When I make the recursive call to the makefile for target `all_hid`, I know that the target `all` is being evaluated.  This means that the `minify_css.php` dependency has already been processed, so I can guarantee it already exists, an assumption that allows the `$(shell php minify_css.php)` command to be evaluated in the first recursive call to the makefile and operate on the generated file.  The next step was to collect the `CSS_OUTPUT` value and get it into another recursive call.  To do that I once again invoked the makefile recursively, from within an already recursive call, and pass it on the command-line.  Remember that during a call to a makefile only those variables you explicitly export are available in sub-makes, so we can't just set it and then make the recursive call on the next line, it must actually be passed as part of the command-line.  In the next level recursive makefile, when we call the `print_css_hid` target, the variable will appear to have been set from the command-line and can be used.

#### Sub-make Considerations

In this case you're actually calling your own makefile recursively, so a concern has to be that all your other variables aren't set up correctly.  Luckily this doesn't happen.  Any command-line values for options passed to the original command-line are automatically provided to every sub-invocation of make called from within the file.  Since the only sources of input that can affect construction of your variables within a makefile are the contents of directories you're operating on, command-line settings, the directory the makefile was called from, and settings within the makefile itself, you just have to make sure you aren't doing something like accidentally including your newly generated file in a "sources" list during nested calls to make and you can guarantee the environment will be set up the same.