# gnu make: how to automatically list and build all targets

Tags: makefile

Suppose I have the following Makefile:

```
RM = rm -f
FLAGS =  -Cr -O1 -gv -gw -g -vw
builddir = ./build/
TD = ./tasks/

all: example1 example3 example5

example1:  

    fpc 01_Kreisumfang.pas $(FLAGS) -o$(builddir)01_Kreisumfang

example3:

    fpc 03_EuroBetrag3.pas $(FLAGS) -o$(builddir)03_EuroBetrag3

example5:

    fpc 05_Dreiecke.pas $(FLAGS) -o$(builddir)05_Dreieck

clean:

    $(RM) $(builddir)*
```

At a certain point my Makefile grows to `example112` ..., 
is there a way to define all automatically with out needing to type in all 
the targets? I don't want to do this:

```
all: example1 example3 example5 ... example112
```

Can I do something like this?

```
all: (MAGIC to Exclude clean)?
```

So instead of having to type all the targets, I want make to detect all the
targets and exclude a certain list.

#### update:

I found the following possible hint:

```
 make -rpn | sed -n -e '/^$/ { n ; /^[^ ]*:/p }' |egrep -v -E '(all|clean)'
```

I don't know how to make this a target by itself, I tried with:

```
TARGETS =: $(shell make -rpn | sed -n -e '/^$$/ { n ; /^[^ ]*:/p }' |egrep -v -E '(all|clean)')
```

But it seems to be wrong. Not only it is wrong, it will cause a silly recursion.

So this solution is only available as a shell command, not within the Makefile itself.

Well, make seems to be just cryptic here. The most reasonable solution I found is to create a script and use that:

```
$ cat doall.sh 
#!/bin/bash
for i in `make -rpn | sed -n -e '/^$/ { n ; /^[^ ]*:/p }' | sed -e 's/://' | egrep -v -E '(all|clean)'`; 
    do make $i; 
done
```

It seems impossible to create it as a make target, or that the ROI on this is very low  ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get the list of targets in a makefile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219255/how-do-you-get-the-list-of-targets-in-a-makefile)

Comment: You need to duplicate any literal dollar sign inside a Makefile.

Comment: @tripleee, even if I change that, there is still no way around make calling it's self ... How would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this out using a for loop. Check if this simple example works for you. Took the command from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373081/assign-a-makefile-variable-value-to-a-bash-command-result) post.

```
RM = rm -f
FLAGS =  -Cr -O1 -gv -gw -g -vw
builddir = ./build/
TD = ./tasks/
SHELL := /bin/bash

targets=$(shell for file in `find . -name '*.pas' -type f -printf "%f\n" | sed 's/\..*/\.out/'`; do echo "$$file "; done;)

all: $(targets)

%.out:%.pas
  fpc $< $(FLAGS) -o (builddir)$@

clean:
    $(RM) $(builddir)*
```

Comment: you are assuming all my targets are called example. Which is fine for now, how would it be when I start having other names?

Comment: it will try to execute the files themselves.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I think now I got the problem. Check the new edit.

Comment: you are searching for .h files, I am trying to compile .pas files. Why are you adding the word .targets? and finally, it just echoing a list of the files but it does not execute the compiler

Comment: el_tenedor, your solution now makes it easy to compile many pascal programs in one make file , thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've been using

```
make -qp | awk -F':' '/^[a-zA-Z0-9][^$#\/\t=]*:([^=]|$)/ {split($1,A,/ /);for(i in A)print A[i]}'
```

(Saved as `make-t`) to list all targets.

If you want to build all real targets, then get a listing of all targets that aren't phony:

```
make -qp | grep -P '^[.a-zA-Z0-9][^$#\/\t=]*:([^=]|$)' |
tee >(cut -d: -f1 ) >(grep '^\s*\.PHONY\s*:' |cut -d: -f2) >/dev/null|
tr ' ' '\n' | sed '/^\s*\./ d; /^\s*$/ d' |sort |uniq -u
```

should do the job (this assumes no target names with spaces in them).