# Bash in Make: how to expand dynamic variable names?

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

To illustrate the issue, I created a makefile which first defines a list of cars and then for each car, a list of colours:

```
CARS = Ford Ferrari Mercedes Toyota
Ford_COLOURS = black blue red white
Ferrari_COLOURS = red
Mercedes_COLOURS = black blue silver
Toyota_COLOURS = blue red white
```

Then, I'd like to loop through all colours of every car in one of my make targets:

```
.PHONY: list
list:
    for car in ${CARS} ; do \
        car_colours=$${car}_COLOURS ; \
        echo $${car_colours} = "$${!car_colours}" ; \
        eval colours="$${!car_colours}" ; \
        for colour in $${colours} ; do \
            echo $${colour} ; \
        done ; \
    done
```

As you can see I tried to synthesise the ideas from [this question about *generating* dynamic variable names in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24316587/897968) and some answers to [this question about how to *evaluate* (expand) dynamic names in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16553089/897968).

Unfortunately I get the following output:

```
Ford_COLOURS = 
Ferrari_COLOURS = 
Mercedes_COLOURS = 
Toyota_COLOURS =
```

while I was hoping to get something like this:

```
Ford_COLOURS = black blue red white
black 
blue 
red 
white
Ferrari_COLOURS = red
red
Mercedes_COLOURS = black blue silver
black 
blue 
silver
Toyota_COLOURS = blue red white
blue 
red 
white
```

How would I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the idea in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32576918/bash-in-make-how-to-expand-dynamic-variable-names#comment53010808_32577813) to [Jonathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32577813/897968), I found a way that involves starting another `make` process from within the fragment which executes the inner `for` loop:

```
.PHONY: list
list:
    for car in ${CARS} ; do \
        car_colours_var=$${car}_COLOURS ; \
        ${MAKE} CAR_COLOURS_VAR=$${car_colours_var} single_car ; \
    done

.PHONY: single_car
single_car:
    for colour in ${${CAR_COLOURS_VAR}} ; do \
        echo $${colour} ; \
    done
```

The key is the intermediary `CAR_COLOURS_VAR` which is passed to the child `make` process as a parameter, which can subsequently be expanded by that process via the `${${CAR_COLOURS_VAR}}` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that the shell doesn't know about the lists of *'make_COLOURS'*.  You can use:

```
CARS = Ford Ferrari Mercedes Toyota
Ford_COLOURS = black blue red white
Ferrari_COLOURS = red
Mercedes_COLOURS = black blue silver
Toyota_COLOURS = blue red white

.PHONY: list
list:
        Ford_COLOURS="${Ford_COLOURS}"; \
        Ferrari_COLOURS="${Ferrari_COLOURS}"; \
        Mercedes_COLOURS="${Mercedes_COLOURS}"; \
        Toyota_COLOURS="${Toyota_COLOURS}"; \
        for car in ${CARS} ; do \
            car_colours=$${car}_COLOURS ; \
            echo $${car_colours} = "$${!car_colours}" ; \
            colours="$${!car_colours}" ; \
            for colour in $${colours} ; do \
                echo $${colour} ; \
            done ; \
        done
```

Note that the `eval` in `eval colours="$${!car_colours}"` in the original has lost the `eval`.  When it is present, you get errors such as `/bin/sh: blue: command not found` because the `eval` has `colours=black blue red white` and tries to execute `blue` with the environment variable `colours` set to `black`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately it pretty much defeats the purpose of the `CARS` list because it'd need to be repeated within the loop. I see the `eval` in my code is probably superfluous, but the error you're talking about should have been prevented by the quotes around `$${!car_colours}`, or am I missing something?

Comment: You're missing something; the eval effectively removes the quotes.

Comment: I'm sorry that you can't do what you want, but at least you know why you got the result you did (I got the same result too).  Sometimes, life is a bear.  Are you sure you wouldn't be better of with a real shell script rather than a fragment in a recipe?

Comment: It is definitely good to know that the expansion of variables defined within the makefile aren't available within the fragments, which probably also means that they are expanded only once; before the fragment is executed. I like the makefile to remain self-contained - maybe I'll create another target that executes the inner loop for a single `car` which is passed in by the `list` target which calls `${MAKE}` with an option. If that is even possible.