# How to assign a value to a variable in a Makefile?

Tags: bash, variables, makefile

I was using this question: [Assign a makefile variable value to a bash command result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373081/assign-a-makefile-variable-value-to-a-bash-command-result/2373111#2373111) to try and solve my problem, but it doesn't seem to work.

I have a one-liner to get the current port of a connected Arduino, that I need in my `Makefile` as a parameter:

```
[bf@localhost GameCode]$ arduino-cli board list | grep arduino:megaavr:nona4809 | awk '{ print $1; }'
/dev/ttyACM0
```

As you see this works fine. But now I want to use that in my `Makefile`:

```
BOARD=arduino:megaavr:nona4809
PORT=$(shell arduino-cli board list | grep $$BOARD | awk '{ print $$1; }')
OUTPUT=mycode.hex

program: $(OUTPUT)
     eeprom-program -f $(OUTPUT) -p $(PORT)
```

But, `$(PORT)` seems to be completely empty. I know I can fix this with a shell script, but as this is only a single line, I don't want to clutter my directory with small scripts.

How can I get that command in my Makefile?

Comment: `$$1` is the makefile variable `$1`, which doesn't exist, just as `$$BOARD` is the makefile variable `$BOARD`.

Comment: @Barmar I forgot the `shell` in front, and `$$1` should then be an escaped `$`. After adding `shell` it still doesn't seem to work though.

Comment: @Barmar, okay. Question still stands, how could I escape that one then?

Comment: `grep $$BBOARD` should be `grep $(BBOARD)`. Makefile variables need `$()` around them. You're escaping the `$`, so it's trying to grep a shell variable named `BBOARD`.

Comment: @Barmar yep, got it now. All that escaping and not-escaping confused a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ...

> ```
> BOARD=arduino:megaavr:nona4809
> PORT=$(shell arduino-cli board list | grep $$BOARD | awk '{ print $$1; }')
> ```

... you correctly escape `$1` as `$$1` to pass the former through to the shell.  But you do not want to pass `$BOARD` through to the shell as such.  Rather, you want `make` to expand that one:

```
BOARD=arduino:megaavr:nona4809
PORT=$(shell arduino-cli board list | grep $(BOARD) | awk '{ print $$1; }')
```