# Assigning the output of a shell (CYGWIN) command to a Make variable

Tags: makefile

I want to assign the output of a shell command into a make variable.
this is what I tried:

```
phonegap:
    #download new phonegap
    cd ${SOURCE_PHONEGAP};git pull
    PHONE_VER = $(shell cat d:/path/to/workspace/common/phonegap/VERSION)
    echo phonegap version: ${PHONE_VER}
```

when running MAKE from the command line I get the following:

> PHONE_VER = 1.3.0
>   make: PHONE_VER: Command not found
>    so the shell string is translated to the right value (1.3.0) but something fails after that.

I also tried declaring :

```
PHONE_VER =
```

and then in the command:
        ${PHONE_VER} = $(shell cat d:/path/to/workspace/common/phonegap/VERSION)
or using := or +=.  didn't work

I'm using cygwin (on win 7) with GNU make 3.81

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019989/how-to-assign-the-output-of-a-command-to-a-makefile-variable) and answer - but this doesn't seem to work for me.
I'm obviously missing something (probably basic), but after a day of experimenting I have no clue whats the missing part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't assign variables inside rule recipes.
The first possible solutions is to initialize it somewhere outside the rule, and then use it as regular:

```
PHONE_VER = $(shell cat d:/path/to/workspace/common/phonegap/VERSION)

phonegap: pull_phonegap
    @echo phonegap version: ${PHONE_VER}

pull_phonegap:
    @cd ${SOURCE_PHONEGAP}; git pull
```

This will work fine as far as `PHONE_VER` is recursively expanded (note the `=` sign in assignment), and the actual invocation of `shell cat ...` will appear after satisfying `pull_phonegap` prerequisite.

The other possibility is make `PHONE_VER` variable `target-specific` for `phonegap`:

```
phonegap: PHONE_VER = $(shell cat d:/path/to/workspace/common/phonegap/VERSION)
phonegap: pull_phonegap
    @echo phonegap version: ${PHONE_VER}
```

Finally, if the only thing you want to do is to print the version of downloaded repo, then it would be easier to get rid of variables at all:

```
phonegap: pull_phonegap
    @echo phonegap version:
    @cat ${SOURCE_PHONEGAP}/VERSION

pull_phonegap:
    @cd ${SOURCE_PHONEGAP}; git pull
```

Comment: thanks! great answer - nicely written, clarified and with multiple options. cudos

Answer (score 1):

since recipes are run in shell you can combine commands through &&:

```
PHONE_VER=`cat d:/path/to/workspace/common/phonegap/VERSION` && echo phonegap version: $${PHONE_VER}
```

don't forget to used $$ instead of a single $