# How to run bash to var and use that in string in Makefile?

Tags: bash, makefile

What I want is to run bash command `docker-machine ip default` put the result in a variable and use that variable in a string and `export` that variable to environment variable. But that doesn't work out as I expected.

Here's my `Makefile` so far.

```
IP := $(docker-machine ip default) 
export DATABASE_URL := "postgres://postgres@$(IP)/postgres"
test:
    echo $(DATABASE_URL)
    py.test tests
```

When I run `make test` I get

```
postgres://postgres@ /postgres
```

Comment: You missed `shell` in the `IP` assignment line. You meant `IP := $(shell docker-machine ip default)` to run the `docker-machine` shell command. You are telling make to run the `docker-machine` make function.

Comment: That's perfect! I did that and it works. Can you put that in answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign the output of a command to a Makefile variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019989/how-to-assign-the-output-of-a-command-to-a-makefile-variable)

Answer (score 1):

You need to indicate **shell** command:

```
IP := $(shell docker-machine ip default)
$(warning IP=$(IP))
```