# How to query registry value with makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, nmake

How can I query a registry and save it to a variable inside of a makefile? I am using GNU Make.

```
VARIABLE = reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /f /v VAR

PRINT:
    @echo $(VARIABLE)

SET:
    reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /f /v VAR /t REG_SZ /d "VALUE"
```

Answer (score 0):

`reg` is writing its result to the standard output (so that the results can be redirected to a file, e.g., this line in a batch file

```
set myvar = reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /f /v VAR
```

You can take the same output and read it into a variable using GNU make, e.g., this line in a makefile

```
myvar = $(reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /f /v VAR)
```

Further reading:

- [How to assign the output of a command to a Makefile variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019989/how-to-assign-the-output-of-a-command-to-a-makefile-variable)
- [Reg query](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742028.aspx)