# How to set variables in make from commands containing pipes and variables

Tags: makefile

I have the following make file:

```
deploy.runtime:
    kubectl describe service hello-node -n default | grep "LoadBalancer Ingress:" | awk '{print $$3}'
    $(eval MY_IP=$(kubectl describe service hello-node -n default | grep "LoadBalancer Ingress:" | awk '{print $$3}'))
    @echo IP: $(MY_IP)
```

When I run this, the output I get is:

```
35.198.222.110
IP:
```

It seems like the bariable MY_IP is not being set.  I've also tried running it with back ticks like this:

```
$(eval MY_IP=`kubectl describe service hello-node -n default | grep "LoadBalancer Ingress:" | awk '{print $$3}'`)
```

Which gives me the output:

```
IP: LoadBalancer Ingress: 35.198.222.110
```

I'm really confused about why awk doesn't seem to be getting the correct arguments.  I'm sure it's something to do with escape arguments, but I cannot for the life of me see how.

Comment: Seems like you aren't assigning the value properly.
Try this syntax:
MY_IP=$(kubectl describe service hello-node -n default | grep "LoadBalancer Ingress:" | awk '{print $$3}')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign the output of a command to a Makefile variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019989/how-to-assign-the-output-of-a-command-to-a-makefile-variable)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that I can fix this by adding a 'shell' into the command:

```
$(eval MY_IP=$(shell kubectl describe service hello-node -n default | grep "LoadBalancer Ingress:" | awk '{print $$3}'))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably missed is that the `eval` parameter is expanded by make. So, in:

```
$(eval MY_IP=$(kubectl describe service hello-node -n default | grep "LoadBalancer Ingress:" | awk '{print $$3}'))
```

the `$(kubectl describe...)` is expanded by make as the empty string (unless you have a make variable named `kubectl describe...`, which is unlikely). The `eval` function thus assigns the empty string to the make variable `MY_IP`. It does not happen with back ticks but here you hit another problem: the `MY_IP` variable is assigned:

```
`kubectl describe... | awk '{print $3}'`
```

not the result of its evaluation by the shell. Note that the `$$3` has been transformed in `$3` by make when it expanded the `eval` parameter. And it is when executing:

```
echo IP: $(MY_IP)
```

that make expands (recursively) the recipe that becomes, step by step:

```
echo IP: `kubectl describe... | awk '{print $3}'`
```

and then:

```
echo IP: `kubectl describe... | awk '{print }'`
```

(unless you have a make variable named `3`). This is what is passed to the shell, leading to what you see. Use `$$$$3`, instead, and it should work as you expect... except that the make variable `MY_IP` is not assigned the value you wanted.

The `shell` function, as you noticed, solves all this but you end up with a terrible mixture: a shell command, evaluated by make through the `shell` function, its result assigned to a make variable thanks to the `eval` make function, in the middle of a recipe which is a list of shell commands. I don't know what you want to do but there must be something simpler.

For instance, if you used a make variable just because you couldn't pass a shell variable from one line of your recipe to the next (normal, they are executed by two independent shell invocations), you could reduce your recipe to a single line (but with `; \` line continuation for better readability):

```
deploy.runtime:
    @MY_IP=`kubectl describe... | awk '{print $$3}'`; \
    echo IP: $$MY_IP
```

Here, `MY_IP` is a shell variable and it is still available to the `echo` command because it is part of the same recipe line. Note the double `$` sign in `$$3` and `$$MY_IP` to escape the first expansion by make.

If, instead, you really want to use a make variable, you could assign it as a regular make variable (using back ticks or the `shell` function, as you wish):

```
MY_IP = `kubectl describe... | awk '{print $$3}'`

deploy.runtime:
    @echo IP: $(MY_IP)
```

or:

```
MY_IP = $(shell kubectl describe... | awk '{print $$3}')

deploy.runtime:
    @echo IP: $(MY_IP)
```

**Important note about this last solution:**

The `MY_IP = ...` assignment is a recursive (delayed) assignment, instead of a simple (immediate) assignment `MY_IP := ...`. This means that the shell command is not expanded and executed immediately when you invoke make. It is only when make needs the value of `MY_IP`. So, if the `deploy.runtime` recipe is the only place where there is a reference to the value of `MY_IP`, the `kubectl...` will be executed only if this recipe is executed. For instance, if you have another `clean` target which recipe does not use the value of `MY_IP`, and if you invoke `make clean`, the `kubectl...` will not be executed at all. The drawback is that if you have several places where make needs its value, the `kubectl...` will be executed several times.

If you use the simple assignment, instead:

```
MY_IP := $(shell kubectl describe... | awk '{print $$3}')
```

the `kubectl` command will be executed only once but it will be each time you invoke make, even if its value is not needed.

In case this is a problem, [Mad Scientist](http://make.mad-scientist.net/) has a very nice trick to combine the pros and cons of recursive and simple assignments:

```
MY_IP = $(eval MY_IP := $$(shell kubectl...))$(MY_IP)
```

If you are interested, read [his post about this](http://make.mad-scientist.net/deferred-simple-variable-expansion/). How many `$` you will need for the `awk` command is left as an exercise...