# Does make not support backtick notation?

Tags: bash, makefile

### Scenario

I was running into some trouble trying to assign values from a command into a variable in a makefile. Using backtick notation seems to work fine, but as soon as I use the more modern `$(pwd)` notation, the value of the variable returns nothing.

```sh
$ cat Makefile
FOO=moo
BAR=$(pwd)
BAZ=`pwd`

all: foo bar baz

foo: 
    @echo foo:$(FOO)';'
bar:
    @echo bar:$(BAR)';'
baz:
    @echo baz:$(BAZ)';'
$ make all
foo:moo;
bar:;
baz:/home/mazunki;
```

As you can see, FOO and BAZ work as expected. But not BAR.

### Problem

Let's look at my problem now, by adding some more examples. I'm skipping the echoing, as you get the idea.

```sh
$ cat Makefile
SHELL=/bin/env bash

FOO=dog
BAR=$(pwd)
BAZ=`pwd`
QUZ=`$(FOO)`/cat
ZOT=`\`FOO\``/owl
BIM=`$(BAZ)`/rat
BAM=`\`BAZ\``/pig
BUM=`BUM`/fox

all: foo bar baz quz zot bim bam bum
# targets for all the things

$ make
foo:dog;
bar:;
baz:/home/mazunki;
bash: dog: command not found
quz:/cat;
bash: FOO: command not found
zot:/owl;
bim:pwd/rat;
bash: BAZ: command not found
bam:/pig;
bash: BAZ: command not found
bum:/fox;
```

I really had hopes for BIM. But sadly, it only return the command which I wanted to run instead. I tried adding another layer of `$()` and/or ``` `` ``` to it, but the result is an empty output instead.

My desired output is what I'd get from running `echo -n $(pwd)/rat` in Bash. None of my tested examples allow me to do this. I want to be able to do this, as some of the commands I use for my preface variables are based on initial settings, as such:

```sh
# User settings
ROOT=`pwd`
SRCPATH=$(ROOT)/src/
OBJPATH=$(ROOT)/objects/

# Scripting
SRCFILES=`find $(SRCPATH) -name '*.ext' -printf '%p '`
OBJFILES=`find $(SRCPATH) -name '*.ext' -printf '$(OBJPATH)/%p ' | sed 's/^$(SRCPATH)/^$(OBJPATH)//g; s/.ext;/.obj;/g; s/;$//g'`
```

It might look kind of a convoluted scenario, but I'm doing this for two main reasons: I want it to be highly configurable, without having to edit the commands themselves, and also because I want to learn how to make Makefiles properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, Makefiles do not support backticks in this way. Makefiles are not shell scripts and do not share syntax with bash at all.

Your example with `BAZ` only appears to work because the backticks end up being copied literally to the shell, so the Make variable `BAZ` contains `` `pwd` `` (*not* `/home/mazunki`), and when injected into a shell command, causes the shell to run `` echo `pwd` ``. At no point did Make interpret the backticks in any way.

To invoke a shell command from make, you can use `$(shell ...)`:

```
var := $(shell pwd)
foo:
        @echo $(var)
```

Note that the command is also a Make expression, not a shell command directly, so any `$`s you want to pass to the underlying shell have to be escaped.

Comment: The fact that Makefiles are not Bash really answers it. It's confusing, as they share the same syntax, as both ``` ` ``` and `$()` are part of the language. Was there an original intention of adding full Bash support, or is there another reason for that? Anyway, your answer is perfect.

Comment: Backticks are not part of Make, they're just literals. `$(...)` does something else. For example, Make `$(VAR)` is like Bash `${VAR}` and Make `$(shell CMD)` is like Bash `$(CMD)`.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it is clearer to see the answer immediatly, although the answer below does a great job explaining _why_ it didn't work. Note: `$(shell ...)` is equal to `$$(...)`, and might be easier to use in practice.

Comment: I had to test: It seems `${FOO}` is equivalent and as valid as `$(FOO)` in Make too, it parses and runs seemingly alike. Is there any difference?

Comment: `$(shell ...)` is definitely not equal to `$$(...)`. The former is evaluated by `make` while the latter is the make-escaped string `$(...)` that gets passed to the shell. I haven't even seen `${}` in make before but the man page says it's the same as `$()`

Answer (score 4):

Make doesn't support backticks.  Makefiles are not shell scripts.  However, makefiles do *run* shell scripts, and shell scripts support backticks.  You wrote this:

```
$ cat Makefile
FOO=moo
BAR=$(pwd)
BAZ=`pwd`

all: foo bar baz

foo: 
        @echo foo:$(FOO)';'
bar:
        @echo bar:$(BAR)';'
baz:
        @echo baz:$(BAZ)';'
$ make all
foo:moo;
bar:;
baz:/home/mazunki;
```

The variable assignments simply create variables containing those literal strings, so `FOO` contains the string `moo`, `BAR` contains the string `$(pwd)`, and `BAZ` contains the string `pwd`.

Make only substitutes variables that start with `$` (maybe you can already see why your makefile doesn't work as you wanted).  Nothing else is special to make.  So when make runs the recipe for `foo`, it will replace the make variable `$(FOO)` with its value `moo` and runs the shell command `echo foo:moo';'`.  When make runs the recipe for `baz` it replaces `$(BAZ)` with `pwd` and runs the shell command:

```
echo baz:`pwd`';'
```

and the *shell* (not make) will expand the backticks for you.

When make runs the recipe for `bar`, though, it will replace `$(BAR)` with the value `$(pwd)` which is another make variable, which will be expanded, and this make variable `pwd` is not set, so make expands this to the empty string and runs the shell command `echo bar:';'`.

If you want to use the new-style `$(...)` syntax for shell scripts you *must* escape the `$` so make doesn't treat it as a make variable.  You have to write:

```
BAR=$$(pwd)
```

then it will work as you expect.

You should really read https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reference.html and the associated pages.

Comment: Oh, so `$$(...)` for bash-things, `$(...)` for make-things. Great and simple. Is there a reason they chose to use the same notation? The fact that they're literal strings explains why they didn't work.

Comment: When `make` was created, back in the 1970's, the `$(...)` syntax for the shell didn't exist.  Only backticks existed.  The `$(...)` shell capability wasn't invented until much later; by that time it was far too late to change make's syntax.

Comment: Just to be clear, you must use `$$` for _any_ dollar sign you want to send to the shell, not just `$(...)`.  You have to use it if you want to reference a shell variable, like `$$HOME`, or if you want to use it in a regular expression, like `grep 'foo$$'`, etc.

Comment: Because otherwise it will be a syntax error in make, much like ending a string in bash with a backslash such as `echo "foo\"`, effectively never ending the string. In Make it would wait for the argument to its dollar symbol, in your case a single `'`.

Comment: Note, it's not a syntax error in make.  It will be a syntax error in the recipe that make sends to the shell and will be reported by the shell.  The shell technically won't wait for anything: it's not interactive.  It will just report a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60628899 by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640, adding a working example:

```
SHELL=/bin/env bash

FOO=$(shell pwd)
BAR=$(FOO)/src
BUZ=ext

all: foo bar baz

foo: 
    @echo foo:$(FOO)';'  # returns /home/mazunki
bar:
    @echo bar:$(BAR)';'  # returns /home/mazunki/src
baz:
    find $(BAR) -name '*.$(BUZ)'  # returns all files /home/mazunki/src/**/*.ext
```

Comment: note you have `$(CURDIR)` in make to use instead of `$(shell pwd)`