# `$(shell <command)` in makefile returns empty on Windows sometimes

Tags: windows, git, shell, makefile, git-bash

I'm trying to run this couple of lines to get the git commit in a makefile, outside of any recipe

```
GIT_VERSION := $(shell cd "C:\Users\made\up\filepath" && git describe --always)
$(info GIT_VERSION is '$(GIT_VERSION)')
```

But it always prints `GIT_VERSION is ''`

However, if I run

```
PWD := $(shell cd "C:\Users\made\up\filepath" && pwd)
$(info PWD is $(PWD))
```

it prints out `PWD is /cygdrive/c/Users/made/up/filepath` as I might expect.

This led me to think there was something wrong with the shell the makefile was using. `SHELL := $(shell echo $$SHELL)` gives `/bin/bash`, which I note is different from the `/usr/bin/bash` that opening a git-bash shell gives me, although I'm not sure how to interpret this, being on Windows. Any clue how I can start getting some output from the `git` call?

---

update: still struggling with this. Have tried the `-C` git option as reccommended in comments, [wrapping in eval](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36787979/1103752), still getting nothing in `GIT_VERSION`

Comment: As an aside, assigning to `PWD` is dangerous, because `PWD` is reset every time you use `cd`.

Comment: Does it help if instead of actually changing directory, you just use `git`'s `-C` option to tell it where to look?  `GIT_VERSION := $(shell git -C "C:\Users\made\up\filepath" describe --always)`.  Aside from minimizing use of `cd` being a good practice, that has the advantage that it will induce an error message instead of failing silently if the target directory does not exist or is inaccessible.

Comment: @JohnBollinger no change :( in fact, even if I do put in a made up filepath, I still get nothing out. It's almost like `git` always fails silently in this shell

Comment: As a diagnostic tool, try using `set +x` inside your shell command, to make it print the commands it runs to stderr (or other chosen bash file descriptor, if using bash, where `-x` is fancy and configurable). Meanwhile, note that it's a good idea to use *forward* slashes so that you don't have to quote some of your backslashes.

Comment: Are you sure you're cd'ing in to a functioning repo? One way to get the behavior you're describing is to redirect stderr and run `git describe` in a directory that's not in any repository Git can recognize.

Comment: @jthill yeah, the `$(shell cd "C:\Users\made\up\filepath" && pwd)` test confirms the directory is right

Comment: FWIW: on linux, with some specific shell errors, the output gets sent to stderr instead of stdout : I wanted to test `VAR:=$(shell echo foo && false); $(info got: $(VAR))` (which outputs `got: foo`, even though the script exits with non zero code), but due to a phat phingers condition ;) I first typed `VAR:=$(shell echo foo && fale); $(info got: $(VAR))`, which printed *on stderr*: `/bin/sh: 1: fale: not found \n foo` and VAR was empty.

Comment: tested one more thing: the above seems to be triggered by `exit 127` (not by any other exit code). tested on Ubuntu 22.10, with GNU Make 4.3 built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu